# Apache does not open pages on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, http-status-code-403

I've got [Apache 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server#Development) with PHP installed on my Raspberry Pi and when I request `index.php` it loads fine, but when I try to request any subfolders or any other file (`strandsort.cs`in this example - could as well be anything.txt, just not HTML/PHP to be parsed), I get `403 access denied`, but when I request file that should be parsed (`i2.php`) I get a blank page.

Also probably worth noting, `phpmyadmin` seems to work fine.

I configured the configuration in:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

And set the `AllowOverride` to `ALL`.

Here's the error:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://raspberryIP/
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/i2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php$ http://raspberryIP/
```

Where "RaspberryIP" is the IP address of the device.

Comment: The problem is a permission issue. What is the user running Apache and what is the result of `stat` on that file?

Comment: @JakeGould. Yeah, guess the server would stop for 30 secs otherwise :)

Comment: Actually, I was a bit ironic. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://raspberryIP/
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/i2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php$ http://raspberryIP/
```

So this seems to be a permissions issue with the file `/var/www/i2.php`. What user owns that file?  Is Apache able to read that file? What is the output if you run this command from the command line:

```
ls -la /var/www/i2.php
```

Additionally, what do the Apache error logs say? They should be located in:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

And you can follow their output using `tail` like so:

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/apache2/access.log
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

These paths are based on a standard Ubuntu 12.04 install, but should be the same for CentOS & whatever Debian variant you are using in the Raspberry PI.

Just so you know, this issue is not idiosyncratic to a Raspberry PI setup but is really a standard Linux Apache service issue. So the debugging techniques used for full-fledged servers can work here as well.

Also, what are the contents of your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file? That is the real file that `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` is simply a symbolic link to. The default Apache `default` file can be confusing & contains a lot of redundant commands. This is the stripped down version I like to use when setting up Apache in Ubuntu:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

Note there is no `AllowOverride All` in this. The whole purpose of `AllowOverride` is to allow the parsing of `.htaccess` files & at this stage that should not be a factor. If you feel it is needed you can add that to this configuration like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:** The original poster posted the `ls -la` output which is as follows:

```
-rw------- 1 pi www-data 21 May  1 14:10 /var/www/i2.php
```

That seems correct, but I would recommend at least trying to adjust the permissions so all can read that file like this:

```
sudo chmod a+r /var/www/i2.php
```

Also, in the Apache `access.log`—which the original poster also provides in the comments—it says:

```
[Sun May 04 18:00:02 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/i2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Which makes me think there is an error in the PHP coding within `i2.php`? Can you check the content in there & maybe just create a simple PHP file that just has the following to see what happens:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

All that said, perhaps it would be best if you adjust permissions for the *whole* `/var/www/` directory like this.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/
```

The `755` will apply read, write & execute permissions for the owner, and read & execute permissions for the group & others. The `-R` flag indicates this should be recursive through the whole `/var/www/` directory & subfolders.

**ANOTHER EDIT:** Looking at the original poster’s `access.log` it seems that there might have been a permissions issue directly connected to an `.htaccess`:

```
[Sun May 04 17:46:10 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun May 04 17:46:11 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun May 04 17:46:11 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun May 04 17:46:11 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun May 04 17:46:12 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun May 04 17:46:12 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sun May 04 17:46:12 2014] [crit] [client 192.168.1.2] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

So while doing a blanket permissions change on `/var/www/` solved the issue, perhaps the permissions issue was based in `/var/www/js/.htaccess` or even the parent `/var/www/js/` directory as well? The reason I point this out is blanket permissions changes like `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/` can solve the issue, but sometimes it’s better to know where the exact problem is coming from so that you aren’t as confused as to what really happened.

Comment: +1 for providing problem solving techniques for future use aswell.

Comment: `ls -la /var/www/i2.php` prints: `-rw------- 1 pi www-data 21 May  1 14:10 /var/www/i2.php` the access.log is quite long, here it is: http://pastebin.com/TbPBf7WE
Oh and the files are owned by default user, since I upload them using ftp.

Comment: here's the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` content: http://pastebin.com/YuMSCDNm